# how to save xml files using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I tried to

> 1) load an xml file using javascript as an object, say **note.xml**
>
> 2) then save the object to a new xml file, say **note_new.xml**

I did 1) but failed 2)

I tried to use method save() to do 2).  After my failure, I checked ms site and they said save() is not supported....

could some one enlighten me how to do the save?

thank you!

here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>W3Schools Internal Note</h1>
<p><b>To:</b> <span id="to"></span><br />
<b>From:</b> <span id="from"></span><br />
<b>Message:</b> <span id="message"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.ActiveXObject){
alert("there is ActiveXObject");
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async=false; 
xmlDoc.load("note.xml"); 
}else{
alert("i am not withActiveXObject!");
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("GET","note.xml",false);
xhttp.send("");
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
}
xmlDoc.save("note_new.xml"); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

update:

seems this is related to security issue.  I appologize to those experienced programmers for my putting this question in a rush because it seems a newbie question.

Comment: Where do you want to save it? Client, server?

Comment: thank you, oedo, could you please tell me what I need to do?  I really got very good answers to my previous questions..  Should I do something to these answers?  If so....where to go?  sorry I'm really new to this site...

Comment: To Nick: thanks!  What I tried to do is really just to create a simple interface on my pc and use it only by myself.  Since I want to use xml as data storage and javascript as driving engine, I looked for the method to upload and download.  Seems Microsoft only allow VB to do the save...is there a security reason for not supporinting save() in other languages?

thanks.

Comment: @user311884 - whichever answer you think is best, just click the checkmark associated with it to accept it.

Comment: yes, i got them!  they are all very nice answers! thank you, SB, and oedo!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is: javaScript does not have an input/output (`I/O`) API as it is a client-side scripting language and consequently has no access to the file system via the server. You would need to use a server-side scripting language to save data to a server. There may be hacks to solve your problem client-side, but they are probably either unsave or otherwise buggy. (btw: what api is the `save` method member of? Did you make that up?)

What you can do is save data temporarily to any DOM element (e.g. window, or a javaScript) object. There is however no way to make these changes permanent.

In your case, looking in to `PHP` scripting might be the best way to go.

Comment: nice answer.  i was trying to avoid installing an addtional software ...thank you!

Comment: Hi, you're welcome! PHP is pretty accessible. So, no worries there.
For what it's worth: for more complex applications there's absolutely no way around learning server-side scripting as you will need the capabilities of high-level programming languages such as `Java` (JSP/Servlets) or `C#` (ASP/.NET) for the logic of your application. If you split responsibilites between those and a client-side scripting (for user interaction) in an intelligent manner, then that will make things a lot easier (i.e. less convoluted, more structured) in the long run. So, there really is no good reason tu shun it.

Comment: Again, thank you for your wonderful advince!  I'll try to bring PHP into the picture.  have a great evening!

Comment: Welcome. Good luck with your project and thanks for accepting my answer!