# Javascript: Change element nodes

Tags: javascript, xml, nodes

So I have a xml document loaded in JavaScript variable.

Xml looks like this:

```
<root>  
    <pp>test<ii>sample italic</ii> text after italic</pp>  
</root>
```

Then I have an input box where the content of `<pp>` element is written out.

Like this: `test<ii>sample italic</ii> text after italic`

Note that text in input box contains Xml tags.

User can then change the text in input box.
Like so: `test<ii>sample BB italic</ii> and <bb>bold </bb> text after`

Now I need to save this modified text back to Xml variable.

How do I do that?

**EDIT 1**
Question has nothing to do with saving to actual file. I just need to save/change modified data back to Xml variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could look at this link it would probably help you : http://www.ehow.com/how_5933380_change-values-xml-javascript.html

Or here, those are two goo tutorial : http://www.devguru.com/features/tutorials/xml_javascript/xml_javascript.asp

Are you reading your xml from a file ?

**To create a node :**

var theNewParagraph = document.createElement('p');
var theTextOfTheParagraph = document.createTextNode('Some content.');
theNewParagraph.appendChild(theTextOfTheParagraph);
document.getElementById('someElementId').appendChild(theNewParagraph);

Taken from this : http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics

Comment: That loads the XML file and enables you to edit the nodes, but there is no mechanism to save the file.

Comment: look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797803/how-to-save-xml-files-using-javascript

Comment: Okay, so the XML file is locally? I did not know that.

Comment: Changing value directly on nodes that exist isn't a problem. How do I add that <bb></bb> to nodes list?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send the data via Ajax to a server-side script, that handles the rewriting of the file. Client-side Javascript cannot solve this problem.

Comment: But I need to modify the content of variable. Saving to file is not the problem here.

Comment: Why don´t you send a string containing your XML to the server script like that: `"<root><pp>" + document.getElementById("yourInputBox").value + "</pp></root>"`?

Comment: Becouse xml is a lot more complicated then this sample, and I need to keep it as DOMDocument all the time, not as string.