# how to update xml file after using removeChild() method

Tags: javascript, xml, jsp, removechild

I have xml file called "movies.xml". I need to remove the first movie from it, so I created "delete.jsp" file contains the code required.

both files are existed in Java web project folder made by Netbeans and I use Apache Tomcat server for localhost

**movies.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<movies>
    <movie>
        <Title>Journey to the Edge of the Universe</Title>
        <Date>7 December 2008</Date>
        <Publisher>National Geographic</Publisher>
        <Description>
            A journey through space and time.
        </Description>
    </movie>

    <movie>
        <Title>Sea Monsters: A Prehistoric Adventure</Title>
        <Date>5 October 2007</Date>
        <Publisher>National Geographic</Publisher>
        <Description>
            A journey to the bottom of the ancient oceans dramatizes awe-inspiring creatures.
        </Description>
    </movie>
</movies>
```

**delete.jsp**

```
<script>
            function loadXMLDoc() {
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        deleteMovie(this);
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "movies.xml", true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

            function deleteMovie(xml) {
                var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
                x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("movie")[0];
                x.parentNode.removeChild(x);
            }
</script>
```

The code works fine but when I open the xml file, I can't see any changes.

What is the best way to save or update the xml file after removing/inserting or any modification without any other language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REMOVE**

**Remove an Element Node**

Suppose "movie.xml" is loaded xmlDoc
Set the variable x to be the element node to remove
Remove the element node by using the removeChild() method from the parent node

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("movie")[0];
 x.documentElement.removeChild(x);
```

**Remove Myself - RemoveChange the Current Value of a Text Node**

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("movie")[0];

x[0].parentNodechildNodes[0].removeChild(x);nodeValue = "new content"
```

**Remove a Text NodeChange an Attribute Using setAttribute()**

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("movie")[0];
y = x.childNodes[0];
x[0].removeChildsetAttribute(y"category","name");
```

**Clear a Text NodeChange an Attribute Using nodeValue**

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("movie")[0].childNodes[0]getAttributeNode("category").nodeValue = "";"name";
```

Reference: W3 schools

**UPDATE:**

**Change the Value of a Text Node**

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("movie")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "new content"
```

**Change an Attribute Using setAttribute()**

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("movie")[0].setAttribute("category","name");
```

**Change an Attribute Using nodeValue**

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("movie")[0].getAttributeNode("category").nodeValue = "name";
```

Try it Yourself »

[**Remove**](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_remove_nodevalue)

[**Update**](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_change_nodevalue)

Obs.: The nodeValue property is the value of a attribute node. Changing the value property changes the value of the attribute.

**Your problem is:** javaScript does not have an input/output (I/O) API as it is a client-side scripting language and consequently has no access to the file system via the server. You would need to use a server-side scripting language to save data to a server. There may be hacks to solve your problem client-side, but they are probably either unsave or otherwise buggy. (btw: what api is the save method member of? Did you make that up?)

What you can do is save data temporarily to any DOM element (e.g. window, or a javaScript) object. There is however no way to make these changes permanent.

In your case, looking in to PHP or Node js scripting might be the best way to go.
But the codes here works.
Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797803/how-to-save-xml-files-using-javascript)

Comment: I want to modify nodes not attributes. BTW, the file still not updated. thanks for your help

Comment: I edit the answer: `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("movie")[0].getAttributeNode("category").nodeValue = "name";`

Comment: can you tell me what 'y' refers to in this code? x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("movie")[0];
 x.documentElement.removeChild(y);

Comment: In this example I put the code according to your `x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("movie")[0]; x.documentElement.removeChild(x); `

Comment: Test the links Remove and Update with you code, and say me if work... It works here.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my purpose. I want to save changes to the xml file permanently after removing the first node from it. Thanks